# angular2 - ngModel not working on labels (ng2-bootstrap, paper-kit)

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, angular2-ngmodel

For me, `[(ngModel)]="foo"` does not work in labels which are used to restyle default HTML5 form controls, more precisely radio buttons. The goal is to use these to change values like with default input radios. I currently use ng2-bootstrap, but also tried the paper-kit (http://www.creative-tim.com/live/paper-kit).

When using the documented usage of ng2-bootstrap (https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/buttons)

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" name="test" [(ngModel)]="foo" btnRadio="foo">foo</label>
```

I get this error:

```
core.umd.js:3468 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'test'
at resolvePromise (zone.js:429)
at zone.js:465
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:236)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6233)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:136)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:368)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:308)
```

This might be fixed using the `ngDefaultControl` attribute in the label, still `[(ngModel)]` is ignored and not propagated. The same issue happens on the usage of paper-kit.

It works on normal radio buttons without any issues.

Comment: You want to change the label styling based on some model ?

Comment: No, I want to use the label as an input to change values, see https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/buttons @ radios for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ButtonsModule` to `imports` of the module where you want to use them

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ButtonsModule],
  declarations: [...],
  ...
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: that would probably fix the problem if systemjs would find it, Still I don't get, why ngModel does not like other labels like the ones from Paper-Kit, but that's another discussion

Comment: `ngModel` requires `ControlValueAccessor` to be implemented in the component where it is applied (or provided by some other means for the matching selector). If the components are not properly imported, they won't be instantiated on the elements. If they are not instantiated, there is no `ControlValueAccessor` hence `ngModel` can't be applied.

Comment: so this means if I want to use e.g. paper-kit buttons, I need to implement a custom `ControlValueAccessor`?

Comment: If they are not Angular2 components you can't use `ngModel` with them. Sometimes adding `ngDefaultControl` helps, but not always (don't know exactly what it does). This doesn't mean you can't use these widgets with Angular at all, you just can't use `ngModel` to bind the value. You can use Angular2 binding to bind to any property, attribute, or event using the actual name like `(some-event)="doSomething($event)"` or `[attr.value]="someProp"`

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you very much for this clarifying answer :)

Comment: There are `ControlValueAccessor` implementations provided by Angular2 for the `<input>` element for most `type="..."` variants, this is why it works for these by default, but there is no such `ControlValueAccessor` for `<label>` or all other kind of elements provided out-of-the box.